# Google fonts issue

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Here is the font that I want to use https://www.google.com/get/noto/#/family/noto-sans

I don't want to download this and use. I want to use it directly from google webfonts.

But when I try to use it from this page https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Noto+Sans getting issue in utf characters. In fact on first link I can see language between available languages.

This is example of first link on my language:

[image]

And here is what I get when I use it from second link (web fonts):

http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/08/10/c13/5d9/24da6d7596f2129a32dda1c561e7545b2fdafe9c.jpg

As you see the character `ə` looks different in results. How to get Noto Sans for specific language from google webfonts?

Comment: Show your code and explain what you regard as wrong with the result.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Noto+Sans, go to the second step and select the character sets that you want to include for your language.